# Calling native code from JavaScript without registering Content URIs in Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: javascript, cordova, win-universal-app

I am working on application which is using Cordova + Windows 10 Universal Application. As per the new security standards for Windows 10 Universal application. If I want to execute any native command from Cordova JavaScript I need to add Content URIs in Application Manifest.

Is there any way/back-door to execute native methods without registering Content URIs in ApplicationContentUriRules?

Comment: have you tried creating a cordova plugin? http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/plugin.html

Comment: Yes, We have created plug-in.js for windows phone. The issues is I want to access native code without adding URI in Content URIs section.